# Button is not changing the html?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a function where the button can be clicked so that new text/and elements can be added to the page, but it's not working, I've tried to check why, but all of my syntax seems to be correct. But yet it's not working

```js
Recipes = {};

function Recipe(name, origin, auther, ingredients, directions) {
  this.name = name;
  this.origin = origin;
  this.author = auther;
  this.ingredients = ingredients;
  this.directions = directions;
};

Recipe.prototype.printRecipe = function(){
  var text = "";
  for (var i=0; i < Object.keys(this).length; i++) {
        text += "<br/>" + this[Object.keys(this)[i]];
  };
  return text;
};

var Salad = new Recipe("Fruit Salad", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Apples, Bananas, Berries, Milk, Sugar, Dry fruits", "<ul><li>sdasds</li></ul>");


function AddRecipe(){
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML =   Salad.printRecipe();
};
```

```html
<p id="text">
  To be vanished by javascript
</p>

<button onclick="AddRecipe()">Display Recipe</button>
```

Comment: What is not working ? I could see it working as expected(as per the code written)..

Comment: Does `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = Salad.printRecipe();` produce expected results ?

Comment: How is your code organised?

Comment: You have included the code..Fine!! But Need to specify exactly what's not working !!

Comment: If still you have error post the error here using firebug console

Comment: The problem is that it's not printing it im sorry i forgot

Comment: I've edited your question to move your code into a runnable snippet, and *it works*. So what is different in your real code? Please [edit] your question to explain how the JS is included by your page.

Comment: Ok but why is it not working here?  https://jsfiddle.net/a_kile/o8rgjdat/

Comment: Check the browser console. Your fiddle has the error `AddRecipe is not defined` because by default JSFiddle wraps the JS in an onload handler, which means the `AddRecipe()` function isn't global and can't be accessed from an inline html event handler. If you click the Javascript setup menu in the top-right of the JS window and change the "Load Type" to "No wrap" then it works: https://jsfiddle.net/o8rgjdat/3/

Comment: Thanks, now it works :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nnnnnn mentioned in the comments, JSFiddle defaults you placing your code within an `onload` event handler. Everything except `Recipes` is defined in that scope. When the `onload` handler is finished, everything local to that scope is lost unless you store it somewhere accessible outside that scope.

For a simple fix, add this at the bottom of your code:

```
window.AddRecipe = AddRecipe;
```

This will put `AddRecipe` in the global scope, making it accessible to the button's `onclick` event. Due to `AddRecipe`'s closure, everything that was with it is still accessible to `AddRecipe` even if it's hidden from everything else.

Comment: What's a Closure?

Comment: *"Everything except `Recipes` is defined in that scope."* - And `Recipes` *should* be declared with `var` (which would make it local too) or as a property of `window` (to make it global), so that its scope is set explictly...

Comment: @UdayKiran I'm not entirely clear on that myself. I find it useful to think of a closure as the collection of local objects (variables, other functions) that's attached to functions created in the same scope. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).